# Div is not resizing properly to be the height of its parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the red border that contains the text to stretch to the bottom of the parent div. Height 100% won't do it. It essentially needs to be the same height as the image.

Note: when viewing the demo, it might be worth shrinking your browser window.

How can I get this to size properly when the 3:2 image is setting the height?

Many thanks for any help!

```css
.the-window {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.the-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.the-image {
  float: left;
  background-size: cover !important;
  width: 45%;
  background-position: center center !important;
  display: block;
  background: pink;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}

.the-details {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
  height: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.the-header {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-window">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="the-image" style="background:url('#')">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Aspect_ratio_-_3x2.svg/270px-Aspect_ratio_-_3x2.svg.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="the-details">
    <h4 class="the-header"><a href="#">Some text will be going in here</a></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's something common. If a parent hasn't got an height defined, the children cannot have the height as 100%, because of the parent, even if a sibling is bigger, the height cannot be 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
/* commented out the unnecessary styles */

* {box-sizing:border-box} /* use * {box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0} to keep the same height of both all the way up when resized vertically */
html, body {margin:0}

.the-window {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*height: auto;*/
  /*float: left;*/
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline, where flex-items have the same height by default, which is dictated by the height of the "tallest" one / can also use the display: inline-flex if you only want it to take the contents width */
}

.the-image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%; /* modified */
  max-height: 100vh; /* vertically responsive */
  margin: 0;
}
.the-image {
  /*float: left;*/
  background-size: cover !important;
  /*width: 45%;*/
  background-position: center center !important;
  /*display: block;*/
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}
.the-details {
  /*flex: 1; uncomment if you want it to take the remaining horizontal space*/
  /*display: block;*/
  /*float: left;*/
  /*width: 55%;*/
  /*height: 80px;*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.the-header {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-window">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="the-image" style="background:url('#')">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Aspect_ratio_-_3x2.svg/270px-Aspect_ratio_-_3x2.svg.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="the-details">
    <h4 class="the-header"><a href="#">Some text will be going in here</a></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use flexbox, as already shown in another answer. Another way is to put the image inside the "details" container (which has 100% width, or any desired width), float the image to the left and add `height: auto` and `overflow: auto` to its container to make it wrap the complete height of the image.

I erased the unnecessary CSS in the following snippet and added a `margin-right` to the image to create some distance to the text:

```css
.the-details {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.the-details img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.the-header {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="the-window">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="the-details">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Aspect_ratio_-_3x2.svg/270px-Aspect_ratio_-_3x2.svg.png" alt="">
      <h4 class="the-header"><a href="#">Some text will be going in here</a></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the height from `.the-details` then add `display:flex; align-items:stretch;` to the style of `.the-window` and give `.the-image` `width:100%`